# Tablet won't recognize OTG flash drive

Tags: samsung, usb-on-the-go

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab S2 8.0. It's up to date with everything. Up until just now, I've never had a problem connecting external storage devices to my tablet using an OTG cable. Earlier today, it worked fine.

Later, I tried to connect a device but it wouldn't mount. I tried a second cable. I then tried a different USB storage device. No luck. I tried rebooting the tablet. No luck. (One of the devices asks if I want to connect and that came on for a second then disappeared. Since then no luck with anything.)

This happened once before and by blowing air into the micro USB port I must have dislodged some dust and it worked. I tried that again but had no luck.

The SD card in the SD card slot is working fine.

To recap, I have tried:

- Three different OTG cables
- Two different USB storage devices
- Restart, turn on and off, soft reset of the tablet.
- OTG troubleshooter isn't finding any OTG even when physically connected.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Probably not getting enough power, try with Y cable

Comment: I doubt that's the problem since both storage devices worked fine just prior to it not working.

Answer (score 1):

USB settings are likely clobbered. Samsung tech support cleared up the issue for me with these steps:

1. Go to Settings → Apps → click on 3 dot menu → Show system apps → USB settings → Storage
2. Clear data (will not remove files or personal data)→Settings→General Management→ Reset (will not remove files or personal data)→Reset settings.
3. Approve all in the second step and tablet will automatically restart.

I tested with an OTG device and mine worked.

Comment: Please be aware that on older versions of android on this Samsung device when you perform the steps in section 1 and move on to the General Management tab in Settings to apply step two, your only reset options are a Network settings reset and a Factory Data Reset. Both of these options will remove personal file data so BEWARE.

Comment: I tried a modified version the suggestion from Bob Quincy. I cleared the data for the USBSettings system app. But instead of doing a Reset I rebooted. After the tablet finished rebooting, I tried reading an SD card with my OTG reader and it worked.
I did this with a Samsung Tab A 10.1" (SM-T510). Thank you Bob.